# Monadic Programming in C#

Tags: c#, linq, haskell, functional-programming, monads

In Haskell, we have the `filterM` function. The source code for it is:

```
filterM          :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM _ []     =  return []
filterM p (x:xs) =  do
flg <- p x
ys  <- filterM p xs
return (if flg then x:ys else ys)
```

Translating from do notation:

```
filterM          :: (Monad m) => (a -> m Bool) -> [a] -> m [a]
filterM _ []     =  return []
filterM p (x:xs) =  p x >>= \flg -> 
                    filterM p xs >>= \ys -> 
                    return(if flg then x:ys else ys)
```

To the best of my understanding, `>>=` on lists in Haskell and `SelectMany` on `IEnumerable`in C# are the same operation and so, this code should work just fine:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<A>> WhereM<A>(this IEnumerable<A> list, Func<A, IEnumerable<bool>> predicate)
    {
        // Like Haskells null
        if (list.Null())
        {
            return new List<List<A>> {new List<A>()};
        }
        else
        {
            var x = list.First();
            var xs = list.Tail(); // Like Haskells tail

            return new List<IEnumerable<A>>
                {
                    predicate(x).SelectMany(flg => xs.WhereM(predicate).SelectMany(ys =>
                        {
                            if (flg)
                            {
                                return (new List<A> {x}).Concat(ys);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                return ys;
                            }
                        }))
                };
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone point me to what's wrong here?

Comment: Please define "it doesn't work" i.e. show the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My C# is a bit rusty, but it looks like your base case is wrong. You're returning the equivalent of `[]` (an empty list) while the Haskell version returns `[[]]` (a list containing an empty list).

Your recursive case has the same problem. For example, in the `else` branch the Haskell version returns `[ys]` while your version returns `ys`. Remember that `return` in the list monad makes a single element list and has nothing to do with the `return` keyword in C#.

Comment: Ha, that's right. Changed it to `new List<List<A>> {new List<A>()}` which changed the problem (the output is different now) but hasn't solved it, since the output still isn't correct. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your C# code is equivalent to:

```
filterM          :: (a -> [Bool]) -> [a] -> [[a]]
filterM _ []     =  return []
filterM p (x:xs) = 
  return $
    p x >>= \flg -> 
    filterM p xs >>= \ys -> 
    if flg then x:ys else ys
```

I.e. `return` is in the wrong spot.

I would expect something like this:

```
        return predicate(x).SelectMany(flg => 
            xs.WhereM(predicate).SelectMany(ys =>
                new List<IEnumerable<A>> { flg ? (new List<A> {x}).Concat(ys) : ys }))
```